# FileUpload.HasFile always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I am wondering why my method FileUpload.HasFile is always null ..

This is the Xaml I use .

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAddFiles" runat="server" UpdateMode=Conditional>
        <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LkUpload" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddFiles" runat="server">
        <div class="PanelAddFiles">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LkUpload" runat="server" OnClick="LkUpload_Click" Visible="false">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Edit :

I think one of the problem would be this

```
    <form action="Upload/Default.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="frm">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAddFiles" runat="server" UpdateMode=Conditional>
        <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LkUpload" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddFiles" runat="server">
        <div class="PanelAddFiles">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LkUpload" runat="server" OnClick="LkUpload_Click" Visible="false">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
            <!--<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Visible="false" />-->
            <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" />
            <asp:Panel ID="Dropbox" runat="server">
                <div class="dropbox">
                    <div class="dragzone">
                    </div>
                    <span class="message">
                drop files here to upload
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</div>
```

because there is the form of the page, and also the form I use here . I have a dropbox that I show or not if it's IE or not . So when it's IE i just display the fileupload .
Maybe it's because there are two forms that it's not firing anymore ?

Should i Definitly use this AjaxToolkit ?

Comment: Remove `Visible="false"` for the `asp:FileUpload` control

Answer (score 6):

FileUpload doesn't work inside an UpdatePanel. You **must use [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)** from ASPNET AJAX control Toolkit.

---

When you use AsyncFileUpload you must set the right params in the *form* tag, that is placed in your Page or MasterPage:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

If you don't set the right enctype and method **UploadedComplete will never fire**, and you won't be able to get **FileUpload.FileBytes** since **FileUpload.HasFile** returns true only during UploadedComplete execution.

---

Besides, prevoius versions of AsyncFileUpload didn't work on Chrome. Actual version solved the problem.

Comment: So is there another way to use the FileUpload without this update panel and its working ?

Comment: FileUpoad must be put outside the updatepanel: it requires full postback of the page. Without update panel FileUpload works

Comment: When I don't have an update panel and just  <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddFiles" runat="server">
        <div class="PanelAddFiles">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LkUpload" runat="server" OnClick="LkUpload_Click" Visible="false">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>   the FileUpload is still always null